# Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

## Visual Studio 14

VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1

MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1

Does this mean that the user used Visual Studio 2014 IDE for this project? Sorry I am new to this.

If yes, can someone help me on to where to download visual studio 2014 because I am getting error (Unsupported) when opening the project on the Visual Studio 2015. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There was no VS 2014 IDE, Check [this](https://omwtm.blog/2014/12/03/visual-studio-2013-version-numbers-and-updates/) link to view the list of VS versions and update numbers.
Looks like the sln was created using VS 2015. Possibly your VS 2015 installation does not have all the features needed to open the sln. Hence the error. Try enabling the required features.[ex: [here]](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/install/modify-visual-studio.md)

Comment: I don't know what update should I do with the version I am right now. I need to edit the code in this project. Please help me.

Comment: 1) Can you compare the VS version (help->About Microsoft Visual Studio)? 2) Are you getting the error even on opening the .proj file?

Answer (score 0):

To find the correspondence between VS versions and IDE version, see this [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio#History). You must open that file using Visual Studio 2015.
The error you get has to do with missing features.